# 1 of 6 harddisks gone after wakeup/resume from S3 (suspend to RAM)

Tags: linux-kernel, hard-disk, power-management, suspend, sata

For a few days now each time I `systemctl suspend` (S3/Suspend to RAM) my PC one of the hard disks disappears.  There is no `/dev/sdb` any more, though `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdc` through `/dev/sdf` remain.  It is always the same hard disk which disappears.  A SMART long test says the hard disk is quite alright.  Except is disappears upon wakeup, every time, consistently.  The messages show something like this during wakeup (note messages on sdb/sd 2):

```
[191432.762381] ata5: found unknown device (class 0)
[191432.762411] ata6: found unknown device (class 0)
[191433.228546] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[191437.422376] ata6: softreset failed (device not ready)
[191437.422391] ata5: softreset failed (device not ready)
[191438.290401] ata4: found unknown device (class 0)
[191438.450381] ata4: softreset failed (device not ready)
[191438.450414] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[191438.454123] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[191438.608510] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[191438.608521] ata3.00: disable device
[191438.608540] sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[191438.608547] ata3.00: detaching (SCSI 2:0:0:0)
[191438.608554] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Start/Stop Unit failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[191438.608558] sd 2:0:0:0: PM: dpm_run_callback(): scsi_bus_resume+0x0/0x80 returns -5
[191438.608567] sd 2:0:0:0: PM: failed to resume async: error -5
[191438.630402] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[191438.630423] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[191438.630424] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
[191438.630428] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Start/Stop Unit failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[191442.774382] ata6: found unknown device (class 0)
[191442.774417] ata5: found unknown device (class 0)
[191443.174399] ata6: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[191443.266633] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/133
[191443.294401] ata5: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[191443.387415] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
[191443.802389] ata4: found unknown device (class 0)
[191445.942401] ata4: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[191446.128870] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
```

I have included lines from other disks to show that they recover - but not so "sd 2"/"sdb".

This may have started with a recent Linux kernel upgrade but I cannot downgrade easily to check that.  This is a production machine that cannot be rebooted often (I can work without that disk or connect it by USB if necessary).

How can I fix this, perhaps by re-setting the disk manually, or telling the kernel to do what it does upon wakeup/resume, or perhaps there are other error messages to check?

EDIT: Swapped power and SATA cables, that does not help.

EDIT2:

```
# foreach d ( /sys/class/scsi_host/host*/scan )
foreach? echo "- - -" > $d
foreach? echo was $d
foreach? sleep 2
foreach? lsblk
foreach? echo =========
foreach? end
```

... does not help, `/dev/sdb` sadly stays gone.

Comment: Can you reproduce this with Linux 5.18.2? If you can, file a bug report at bugzilla.kernel.org If it's a regression please specify the last version which worked for you. As for forcing the kernel to rescan all the SCSI ports, please use this script: github.com/birdie-github/useful-scripts/blob/master/rescan_scsi

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks, I am still on 5.18.1, will test and let you know. The scan did not reveal the device.

Comment: There aren't any serious fixes in 5.18.2, please file a bug report. What you're describing is still highly unusual, I'd try to use different SATA cables and a different PSU.

Comment: I exchanged power and SATA cables. No help. Perhaps the disk is faulty?

Comment: For the HDD the suspend and resume operations are exactly the same as power off and on. It doesn't sound all too likely. *"PM: dpm_run_callback(): scsi_bus_resume+0x0/0x80 returns -5"* could indicate a power management issue/bug in the kernel, so maybe there's a regression only you are hitting considering you told that some earlier kernels did work. I've found people with similar symptoms: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=276582 https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=76681 https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/sata-disk-problems-4175532754/

Comment: Thanks, bug filed and keeping you updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to contact the manufacturer of the hard disk in question (Toshiba).  They sent a modified firmware which reacts faster to a request to start/boot.  The new firmware sends that signal "I am ready" much earlier (around 1 second after power-up) which the BIOS or Linux kernel seems to expect.  It has not become completely clear to me whether the BIOS/mainboard or the operating system is the culprit and having a timeout that is too small.

I should perhaps add that this was about an enterprise hard disk in a standard home PC.  Perhaps the disk was not designed for a fast startup (which does not exist in the server world).